# ON clause with Hibernate Query interface

Tags: hibernate

I am getting HibernateQueryException,when i use On clause with Left Outer join.

Can anyone suggest me what is the cause.

Regards,

Raj

Comment: The cause is that you made a mistake.  Please provide more detail.

Comment: @Slaks: Query executing fine in any db tool,it failed when i use same query with hibernate

Comment: Oh you have a query; can we see it?

Answer (score 5):

HQL doesn't support `... JOIN ... ON ...` syntax, you can `JOIN` only on defined relationships between entities (`FROM Foo foo JOIN foo.bars bar`).

If you need `JOIN` on arbitrary condition, you can use old-fashioned form `FROM A a, B b WHERE a.x = b.y` (though you can't make outer join this way). Otherwise have to use native SQL query.

**See also:**

- [Chapter 16. HQL: The Hibernate Query Language](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms)
- [Chapter 18. Native SQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html)

Comment: How native SQl query supports this?

Comment: well, technically, with hql 4.3, "on" is actually supported, but in a non-standard way, you have to use "with" - http://www.bmchild.com/2012/05/hibernate-with-clause-hql-equivalent-of.html

Comment: Hibernate 5 supports "on" clause in a native "sql" way. `select history from User user join UserHistory history on user.id = history.user`. Here User and UserHistory are related in one-to-many fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'with' clause:

```
from Cat as cat
left join cat.kittens as kitten
    with kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html