# How to convert the below SQL to JPQL?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpql

How to convert the below SQL to JPQL?

```
SELECT *
FROM SSSRC.NAME_TEST nameTest
LEFT JOIN TTREFERENCE.LOCATION location
ON nameTest.place= location.location_name WHERE nameTest.gender = 'Male'
AND nameTest.age= '50'
AND nameTest.name IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY nameTest.sortby ,location.location_order;
```

I convert like this

```
"SELECT nameTest FROM NameTest nameTest, LEFT JOIN Location location ON nameTest.place = location.location_name WHERE nameTest.age= '50' and nameTest.gender = 'Male' and nameTest.name IS NOT NULL ORDER BY nameTest.sortby ,location.location_order";
```

but

Its not working its giving below error

```
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.0.0-r422266:935683 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "Encountered "location" at character 66, but expected: [",", "GROUP", "HAVING", "INNER", "JOIN", "LEFT", "ORDER", "WHERE", <EOF>]." while parsing JPQL "SELECT nameTest FROM PrintRequest nameTest, LEFT JOIN LOCATION location ON nameTest.place = location.location_name WHERE nameTest.age= '50' and nameTest.gender = 'Male' and nameTest.name IS NOT NULL ORDER BY nameTest.sortby ,location.location_order";. See nested stack trace for original parse error.
      at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:51)
      at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery.newCompilation(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:150)
      at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.newCompilation(QueryImpl.java:670)
      at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compilationFromCache(QueryImpl.java:652)
      at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForCompilation(QueryImpl.java:618)
      at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compileForExecutor(QueryImpl.java:680)
      at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.compile(QueryImpl.java:587)
      at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:985)
```

Comment: Remove the "," between "NameTest" and "LEFT JOIN"

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
"SELECT nameTest
FROM NameTest as nameTest
LEFT JOIN Location
ON nameTest.place = Location.location_name
WHERE nameTest.age = '50' and
nameTest.gender = 'Male' and
nameTest.name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY nameTest.sortby, Location.location_order";
```

Comment: I'm getting following error " Encountered Encountered "JOIN Location AS" at character 61, but expected: [".", "AS", "FETCH", "INNER", "JOIN", "LEFT", <IDENTIFIER>]."

Comment: @stacktome I've updated my answer, so you can try new variant

Comment: still i'm getting the same error "Encountered "LEFT JOIN Location ON" at character 55, but expected: [".", "FETCH", "INNER", "JOIN", "LEFT", "OUTER", <IDENTIFIER>]." while parsing JPQL ""SELECT nameTest FROM NameTest as nameTest LEFT JOIN Location ON nameTest.place = Location.location_name WHERE nameTest.age = '50' and nameTest.gender = 'Male' and nameTest.name IS NOT NULL ORDER BY nameTest.sortby, Location.location_order";"

Comment: @stacktome check another answer, it can be the case

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
    "SELECT nameTest FROM NameTest nameTest 

    LEFT JOIN Location location ON nameTest.place = location.location_name 

    WHERE nameTest.age= '50' and nameTest.gender = 'Male' and nameTest.name IS NOT NULL 

    ORDER BY nameTest.sortby, location.location_order";
```

Note ON clause is defined in the JPA 2.1 and supported in [EclipseLink 2.4](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#LEFT_JOIN) and for hibernate support please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5220962/1047582

---

It seem to me your JPA not supported ON clause. For simple LEFT JOIN you need to change your entity. For example NameTest class has one Location element:

```
public class NameTest{

  @JoinColumn(name = "locationId", referencedColumnName = "location")
  @ManyToOne()
  Location location;

(...)
}
```

In this case the JPQL look like as:

```
SELECT nameTest FROM NameTest nameTest 

        LEFT JOIN nameTest.location location 

        WHERE nameTest.age= '50' and nameTest.gender = 'Male' and nameTest.name IS NOT NULL 

        ORDER BY nameTest.sortby, location.location_order
```